# Nginx proxy wordpress except the preview urls

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I have setup wordpress proxy for all routes but I don't want to proxy the preview urls. The typical url looks like this. I would rather setup the proxy rule so if it contains `preview=true` don't proxy it.

https://www.example.com/slug/?preview_id=2028&preview_nonce=142f805c73&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true

This is what I have so far

```
location ~.*preview_id.* {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Comment: What is the preview? Is it at `/slug/index.html`? Also, you cannot use `location` to test `preview_id` as it's part of the query string. You could use `if ($arg_preview_id) { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

*preview* is a GET-argument, not a part of the URI from the nginx point of view (although it may appear to you as one), so you need to check `$arg_` variables, not the `location`.

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed answer. I can't add if statement and check inside the location because I either get can't proxy inside if statement or `try_files" directive is not allowed here in` based on the way I write my if statement.